# Laravel updateOrInsert deal with foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple columns in `DB` and I need to populate values in those fields. To achieve that I'm using `foreach` loop.

```
$update = [];

foreach ($userPermissions->getPermissionNames() as $t)
{
    if (in_array($t, $permissions))
    {
        $update[] =  [$t => 1];
    }
    else{
        $update[] = [$t => 0];
    }
}
```

The output of this array is here:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "is_admin" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "is_something_else" => 1
  ]
]
```

but when it goes into `updateOrInsert` it fails because the array is not in the right structure.

```
UserPermission::updateOrInsert(['user_id' => $user->id], $update);
```

How to insert those `dynamic` values into the `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about building up a simple array with the key name and value?

```php
foreach ($userPermissions->getPermissionNames() as $t)
{
    // Cast the bool to an int
    $update[$t] = (int) in_array($t, $permissions);
}
```

It should produce something like,

```php
[
    'is_admin' => 1,
    'is_something_else' => 1,
]
```